# VB2010: Export datagrid to Excel only retieving one row

Tags: vb.net

I just want to mention first, I do appreciate everyone who gives of their knowledge to help others learn...

I have been able to piece together code that exports my Datgrid to an Excel file and works fine, except I am only getting the first row of the datagrid. since the datagrid could contain one record, or hundreds, I need all rows to export to Excel.

Here is what I have been able to put together (again, it works fine, file is saved with column headers, but only writes the first row of data from my datagrid):

```
'Export to Excel
    Dim ExApp1 As Excel.Application
    Dim ExWkbk1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ExWksht1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim MisValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    ExApp1 = New Excel.Application
    ExWkbk1 = ExApp1.Workbooks.Add(MisValue)
    ExWksht1 = ExWkbk1.Sheets("sheet1")



    For i = 0 To dg7.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dg7.ColumnCount - 1
            ExWksht1.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dg7(j, i).Value.ToString()
            For k As Integer = 1 To dg7.Columns.Count
                ExWksht1.Cells(1, k) = dg7.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                ExWksht1.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dg7(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ExWksht1.SaveAs("C:\MyExcel.xlsx")
    ExWkbk1.Close()
    ExApp1.Quit()

    releaseObject(ExApp1)
    releaseObject(ExWkbk1)
    releaseObject(ExWksht1)
```

Again, many thsanks in advance for helping me learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it seems to me this is a DataGridView as opposed to a DataGrid since from what I know DataGrid does not have "RowCount" or "ColumnCount" properties in either WinForms or Web.UI (I could be wrong).
If it is so is there a specific reason for

> dg7.RowCount - 2

If the object you are trying to get data from is indeed a DataGridView then I suppose this task is to omit new(empty) rows. If I am correct that you are trying to export data from a DataGridView this way there is a property for the DataGridViewRow that will serve this purpose:

> IsNewRow

So (while I have not used Excel in VB.NET recently) your cycle could be:

```
For i = 0 To dg7.ColumnCount - 1
    ExWksht1Cells(1 , i + 1) = dg7.Columns[i].HeaderText
Next

For i = 0 To dg7.RowCount - 1
    If Not dg7.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
        For j = 0 To dg7.ColumnCount - 1
            ExWksht1.Cells(i+ 2, j + 1) = dg7(i, j).Value.ToString()
        Next
    End If
Next
```

As far as the excel object calls I can't give a reasonable comment since I've not used that object too much.
Let me know if that's useful and/or correct.